# API to check if user signup is spam/invalid?

Tags: spam-prevention, akismet

We have a signup form for companies where user must enter

- first and last name
- their desired subdomain name
- email
- company name

We would like to run the input through some kind of spam/fraud (fake account, accounts with curse words, etc.) verification API which would create a score for the signup input and we could act accordingly.

While googling I only found `akismet` which supports signup mode and user first/last name and email fields, but when testing with `John Doe john.doe@example.org` with user agent set to CURL it says that it's not spam..

Any other solutions out there?